# How to create a calculated field which says "yes" if another field has certain values in Workday?

Tags: workday-api

I have a field called "field 1" which has a row of values "a", "b" , "c" ,"d" , "b" ,"d" , "a" .  I would like to create a calculated field called "field 2" which contains "Yes" or "1" for each row from "field 1" that has a "b" or "d" value. What is the best function to use to create this calculated field?

I tried using some functions within Workday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will create 2 calculated fields:

1. True/False if Field 1 value equals 'b' or 'd'
2. Evaluate Expression Band to say if CF TF is true, then output a value of 1 or Yes, with a default value of 0 or No